# "Rule of Thumb" method to adjust for overstatement bias on a likert scale

Tags: likert, bias

I have a relatively novice question which I have been attempting to peruse the literature for the past hour to address without much success.

I am attempting to test a product concept in a survey for adoption, and would like to have a question with a 5-point rating scale to test the **likelihood to use** the product concept being tested.

I have been told by market research colleagues various permutations of **how to shift from a 5-point scale to a likelihood to use**, (i.e. a value of 5 = 70%, 4 = 40%, 3 = 10%, 2 = 0%, 1 = 0%), but I would prefer to have the method I use vetted before adopting this sort of methodology.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: I would guess that your colleagues' recommendations are based either on intuition or some sort of market research. I am also guessing that the various recommendations wind up not making too much difference. Finally, the right recommendation might vary depending on the type of product.